# .py to .exe file conversion issue

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I'm trying to convert a simple python code (any sample code) into an executable file but on opening the application all I can see is a blank black screen.

I am using:

- Python 3.7
- PyInstaller 3.6
- One file output

I am able to convert the file to .exe using auto-py-to-exe but I don't see any output when I try to run the application.

Comment: It depends what your code is.  Does it generate any output? Does it do what it does even though you see a blank screen? Run your new exe in a command prompt to see what kind of messages you get.

Answer (score 0):

`Pyinstaller` is much easier than other things, you need to install with `pip`:

`pip install pyinstaller`

And then go to the path of your Python file and then:

`pyinstaller -w -F my_file.py`

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this in order:

1. `py -3.7 -m pip uninstall pyinstaller`
2. `py -3.7 -m pip install pyinstaller`
3. `pyinstaller --onefile test.py`

Comment: yeah I forgot to add to re-install it :P. Thx

Answer (score 0):

In general there are some different ways so you can try the below and see if the issue is solved.

1. **auto-py-to-exe** is "A .py to .exe converter using a simple graphical interface built using Eel and PyInstaller in Python.". You can find a quick guide [here](https://dev.to/eshleron/how-to-convert-py-to-exe-step-by-step-guide-3cfi)
2. **PyInstaller** "freezes (packages) Python applications into stand-alone executables, under Windows, GNU/Linux, Mac OS X, FreeBSD, Solaris and AIX." You can find more usage info [here](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html) (also pointed out by @nakE)
3. **py2exe** "is a Python Distutils extension which converts Python scripts into executable Windows programs, able to run without requiring a Python installation.".You can find more usage info [here](https://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Tutorial) (also as pointed out by @Kompocik)

If it is not solved then I am pretty confident that there is an issue with the executed code per se and not the conversion.

Can you please share your code so we can have a look?